# While using smooth, curve color is being changed

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a curve defined like below

```
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].XAxis.Scale.Max = listACSignal[listACSignal.Count - 1].X / 2;
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = false;
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].YAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].XAxis.Type = AxisType.Linear;
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].XAxis.Scale.Format = "";
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].TitleGap = 0;
myCurveACSignal = zgc.MasterPane.PaneList[0].AddCurve(null, listACSignal, Color.Lime, SymbolType.None);
myCurveACSignal.Line.Width = lineWidth;
Fill fillACSignal = new Fill(Color.Blue, Color.Red);
fillACSignal.RangeMin = 1;
fillACSignal.RangeMax = 2;
fillACSignal.Type = FillType.GradientByZ;
myCurveACSignal.Line.GradientFill = fillACSignal;
myCurveACSignal.Line.IsSmooth = true;
myCurveACSignal.Line.SmoothTension = 0.2F;
```

I want to sharpen intersection of lines so I have used the `IsSmooth` property. However it affects the color of the curve. I want my curve blue but if I use `IsSmooth` it shows purple lines. Is there anyway to prevent color changes?

Comment: This is a common problem with anti-aliasing algorithms, especially on algorithms optimized for LCD panels.  They take advantage of the spacing between the R, G, and B subpixels which trades color accuracy for smoothness.  Some people are more sensitive to changes in chroma than others.  I don't know FLOT, but prepare yourself to be miffed if someone just says that this is the nature of the anti-aliasing algorithm.

Comment: If I use `GradientFill` with two different color like my code blue and red it mixes the colors and curve looks purple. If I use same color, it is okay. However I need to label some data so must use different colors. I think I can't use smoothing with gradientfill :/ Thank you for your answer.